# I am not able to get the specific text from specific row of the web table using WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am not able to get the text from the web table. Please see the screen shot below for the text I am looking for. How to get the text Quick App from the below screen shot.

[image: screen of my app.]

In the screen shot, if I find the Quick App then I have to click on Edit link for that User.
Code for xpath count for the table below:

```
//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers']/tbody/tr
```

I have tried to capture the text by using below code:

```
text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers'] 
/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

I am getting Null value after executing the above code.
Please help me in this issue by providing code for it. Help will be appreciated.

```
<table id="ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers" class="btext" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="color:#333333;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;"> <tbody> <tr align="left" style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;"> <tr class="text" style="color: rgb(28, 28, 28); background-color: rgb(249, 182, 115); font-weight: normal; height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$0')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: White; height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$1')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);"> <tr style="background-color: rgb(239, 243, 251); height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$2')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);">
<tr style="background-color: White; height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$3')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);"> <tr style="background-color: rgb(226, 222, 208); height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$4')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);"
<tr style="background-color: White; height: 10px; text-decoration: none;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MasterPlaceHolder$GvUsers','Select$5')" onmouseout="javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);" onmouseover="javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);"> <td>7CUser44</td> <td>Swamy m Kumara</td> <td>Quick App</td> <td>QuickApp User</td> <td>Active</td> <td>halcyon2</td> <td>COTTAGE GROVE </td> <td>WI</td> <td> </tr>




   int xpathcount= driver.findElements(By.xpath((OR.getProperty("xpathcount_Users_ID")))).size();
        System.out.println("Number of rows displayed in Site History table: " +xpathcount);
        int k;
        for (k=1;k<=xpathcount;k++)
        {
            Select table = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers']/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]")));
            text1 = table.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
            System.out.println("Selected User Level is: "+text1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers']/tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]")).getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

Please find the code I have used.

Comment: Are u able to get the row count.  is //table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers']/tbody/tr returning correct count ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i am getting the row count correctly.

Comment: Can you do one small cross check for the texts in User level column.Is this coming under td or some other tag like td/span something like.

Comment: It is coming under td tag only.

Comment: Yeah i think you won't get a good answer. Because if you can't figure out how my answer could satisfy your case, you must need to learn coding in the first place.

Comment: @thotaumamaheshwar, using your HTML and code, it works perfectly fine for me. Suggests the problem is not in what you are showing us. You are using an integer (called `k`)...I would inspect this value as it runs. Is it part of a loop?

Comment: why you are using Select table = new Select(driver...) to find table ?

Comment: That answer i found some where and tried using that. but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Here, i have modified my code as below and worked. Thanks for all the members who tried helping me.

```
int xpathcount=     
driver.findElements(By.xpath((OR.getProperty("xpathcount_Users_ID")))).size();
System.out.println("Number of rows displayed in Site History table: " +xpathcount);
int k;
for (k=2;k<=xpathcount;k++)
{
text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GvUsers']
   /tbody/tr["+k+"]/td[3]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i can give on simple example using python webdriver. but i don't know how to get text using java. see below example

```
word=driver_find_element_by_xpath("xpath value which text you need from web table")
print word.text
```

Answer will be show which you have selected in web table.

Comment: Thanks Senthilkumar for your answer, will try your answer by converting it to Java. and let you know the results.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to give a proper answer with no HTML but here goes something that might help.

```
public void getEditTable(final WebDriver driver, final By table, final String query) {
    List<WebElement> lines = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (WebElement line : lines) {
        List<WebElement> cols = line.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        if (cols.get(2).getText().equals(query)) {
            List<WebElement> actions = cols.get(8).findElement(By.tagName("a"));
            actions.get(0).click();
        }

    }

}
```

Now i have to point out that this would most likely need a lot of work on your side, but maybe you can get the main idea. I do something similar to the web tables for my company CRUD sites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply aimbire, i will check this code and let you know the updates on this.